# Markdown or formatting text in ChatGPT response

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I just have confirmed that using the API with the chat completion, the response is in plain text.

How to format the text from the response, for at least new line, tables, bullet point, heading...Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing the output as markdown should generally work.** You can then work with the parsed markdown, e.g. transform it to HTML or process it how you need. It depends on your use case and the language you're programming in.

Below is an example response from gpt-3.5-turbo for this prompt, fully parsable as a markdown (including tables).

---

*Please, prepare a detailed answer to this question: What are HTML tags? Can you provide me a table with paired tags and another table of unpaired tags with their meaning?*

```
HTML tags are elements used to structure the content and provide instructions about how the content should be displayed on a web page. Tags are represented by opening and closing brackets (< >) and surround the content they affect. Paired tags have both an opening and closing tag, while unpaired tags only have an opening tag.

Here is a table with some commonly used paired/parent tags along with their meanings:

| Paired/Parent Tags | Meaning                               |
|--------------------|---------------------------------------|
| `<html></html>`    | Represents the root of an HTML document|
| `<head></head>`    | Contains meta-information about the HTML document              |
| `<body></body>`    | Represents the visible content on the web page                    |
| `<p></p>`          | Defines a paragraph of text                                           |
| `<a></a>`          | Creates a hyperlink                                                    |
| `<div></div>`      | Groups elements together for styling or scripting purposes                   |
| `<h1></h1>`        | Defines a top-level heading                                           |
| `<table></table>`  | Represents tabular data                                                |

And here is a table with some commonly used unpaired/empty tags and their meanings:

| Unpaired/Empty Tags | Meaning                                     |
|---------------------|---------------------------------------------|
| `<br>`              | Inserts a line break                          |
| `<hr>`              | Represents a thematic break                   |
| `<img>`             | Embeds an image                               |
| `<input>`           | Creates an input control                      |
| `<meta>`            | Provides metadata about the HTML document     |
| `<link>`            | Defines a link between a document and an external resource |
| `<script>`          | Embeds or references an external script       |
| `<style>`           | Contains CSS rules for styling HTML elements  |

These are just a few examples of HTML tags, and there are many more available to structure and format web content. Each tag serves a specific purpose, allowing web developers to create well-organized and visually appealing web pages.
```

Comment: `prepare an answer for a question posted on Stack Overflow` It should be noted that actually posting such an answer is frowned upon as [Generative AI is banned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: @Alejandro Oh, I just wanted to provide an example prompt and answer from the API. I'll update the answer, thanks for the notice!